# How to increase size of short cut icons in Android programmatically

Tags: android

In my application, I am using the below code to create a short cut.

```
 public void createShortcut(Intent intent) {
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconResource = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE);
    Bitmap icon = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON);
    String shortcutLabel = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME);
    Intent shortIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT);

    if (icon == null) {
        if (iconResource != null) {
            Resources resources = null;
            try {
                resources = pm.getResourcesForApplication(iconResource.packageName);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (resources != null) {
                int id = resources.getIdentifier(iconResource.resourceName, null, null);
                if (resources.getDrawable(id) instanceof StateListDrawable) {
                    Drawable d = (resources.getDrawable(id)).getCurrent();
                    icon = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
                } else
                    icon = ((BitmapDrawable) resources.getDrawable(id)).getBitmap();
            }
        }
    }

    if (shortcutLabel != null && shortIntent != null && icon != null) {
        ShortcutSerializableData objectData = AppSharedPref.getInstance().getShortcutSerializableData();
        if (objectData == null) {
            objectData = new ShortcutSerializableData();
            Log.e(TAG, "Serialized data not found");
        }

        if (objectData.apps == null) {
            objectData.apps = new ArrayList();
            Log.e(TAG, "Serialized app not found");
        }


        ShortcutPac pacToAdd = new ShortcutPac();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        if (x >= (width - 250)) {
            y = y + 150;
            x = 40;
        }


        pacToAdd.x = x;
        pacToAdd.y = y;
        pacToAdd.URI = shortIntent.toUri(0);
        pacToAdd.label = shortcutLabel;
        pacToAdd.icon = icon;
        x = x + 250;

        if (HomeActivity.activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            pacToAdd.landscape = true;
        else
            pacToAdd.landscape = false;

        pacToAdd.cacheIcon();
        objectData.apps.add(pacToAdd);
        pacToAdd.addToHome(this, homeView);
        AppSharedPref.getInstance().setShortcutSerializableData(objectData);
    }
}
```

And above code is working and creating short cuts as expected. My question is can change the size of short cut icons? I mean by above code I am getting the size of the icon (for example 50x50) then I am getting the same size of the short cut icon on 7 and 10-inch tablets as well. What I want is to change the size of short cut icons for tablets. I want to show tablets shortcut icon bigger than usual as it is creating for cellphones.

NOTE: In settings of Android OS, if I select display option and from there I can increase the size of icons and texts. But the same thing I want, I want to change the size if short cut icons programmatically. Is it possible? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Icon **display** size is launcher dependent. Luckily you cannot enforce different size user wants.

Comment: Is it possible to change Icon display size via launcher or something?

Comment: Depending on the launcher (ie Nova has such settings). But if i would find any app i installed trying to make its icons bigger than **I** wanted icons to be w/o asking I would be very upset.

Comment: Basically I am creating my own launcher. For that purposes when there is a device tablet there is requirement to make icons size bigger.

Comment: Then what size of icons you display is up to you and it can be any size you baswd on any criteria. I do  ot understand what you ask for then.